Registration Form not sending data into database
I'm trying to make a find my friends clone but i'm currently having issues with the registration form not inputting data into MySQL database.Login form is able to grab info from the database it's just registration form being unable to input.
First is my registration.php and the second is my database connection.I'm completely out of ideas on what could be the issue.As even when I open the error logs i'm not seeing any issues.
<?php


// Check if the form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    var_dump($_POST); // debugging
    
    // database connection
    include_once 'db_connection.php';

    // Initialize an empty array to store error messages
    $errors = [];

    // Get form data and sanitize input
    $username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $confirmPassword = $_POST['confirmPassword'];
    
    // Retrieve latitude and longitude from the form data
    $latitude = $_POST['latitude'] ?? null;
    $longitude = $_POST['longitude'] ?? null;

    // Validate form data
    if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($confirmPassword)) {
        $errors[] = "All fields are required.";
    }

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors[] = "Invalid email format.";
    }

    if ($password !== $confirmPassword) {
        $errors[] = "Passwords do not match.";
    }

    // Check if location consent is given
    $locationConsent = isset($_POST['locationConsent']);

    // Check if username or email already exists
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $errors[] = "Username or email already exists.";
    }

    // If no errors, insert user into database
    if (empty($errors)) {
        // Insert user into database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, latitude, longitude) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $username, $email, $password, $latitude, $longitude);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            // Registration successful, redirect to login page
            header("Location: login.php?registration=success");
            exit();
        } else {
            $errors[] = "Registration failed. Please try again.";
            // Add this line to log the error
            error_log($stmt->error, 0);
        }
    }        
        

    // Close database connection
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Registration</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
        <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br>
        <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password:</label><br>
        <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword"><br>
        <!-- Additional fields like latitude and longitude -->
        <input type="hidden" name="latitude" value="some_value">
        <input type="hidden" name="longitude" value="some_value">
        <input type="checkbox" id="locationConsent" name="locationConsent">
        <label for="locationConsent">I consent to provide my location.</label><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
</body>
</html>


<?php
// Include database configuration
include_once 'db_config.php';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    $error_message = "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error;
    // Log the error
    error_log($error_message, 3, "/var/log/mysql/error.log");
    die($error_message);
} else {
    echo "Connected successfully";
}
?>

mysql> DESCRIBE users;
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field             | Type          | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| id                | int           | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
| username          | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| email             | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| password          | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| latitude          | decimal(10,8) | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| longitude         | decimal(10,8) | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| default_latitude  | decimal(10,8) | YES  |     | 0.00000000 |                |
| default_longitude | decimal(11,8) | YES  |     | 0.00000000 |                |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> completly

enter image description here
This is the page that comes up when I input information and click register.Used var dump just to make sure the inputs were being received correctly and it seems like it is.

Is it redirecting to the success page?

Are you seeing the output of var_dump($_POST);? That will prevent the redirect from working.

You create an array of errors, but don't output it at all or show it to the user. What happens when you try to submit the form?

Never store plain text passwords. Instead use password_hash() and password_verify().

You're going to want a unique constraint on both email and username.

I've edited my post to show the page after registration. Its not the dashboard of my website as i'm trying to just focus on getting it to update mysql. Before i was using the var_dump though the register wasnt updating to mysql. If my dashboard code or html.index code would help I could send it though i doubt those are the issues.

And i plan to hash the passwords once the main functionalities are finished.I was having issue with my login when i was hashing before.

OK. It could be crashing after that. Make sure you've got php and mysqli error reporting fully enabled, and then try again

What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you struggling with the HTML part, the PHP part, or the database part?
